# meteor collection - leaderboard app

Tags: collections, meteor, leaderboard

What am i doing wrong?

I'm building the leaderboard app from meteortips.com 
Trying to build a collection in the database this is my code:

```
new Meteor.Collection('players');
 PlayersList = new Meteor.Collection('players');
    if(Meteor.isClient) {
       console.log("Hello Client");
  }
   if(Meteor.isServer) {
      console.log("Hello Server");
   }
```

Trying out PlayersList on the js console gives me an error:

```
 PlayersList
    ReferenceError: PlayersList is not defined
  message: "PlayersList is not defined"
```

stack: (...)
      stack: function () { [native code] }
     set stack: function () { [native code] }
         **proto**: Error

Answer (score 0):

You’re defining the collection twice. Change:

```
new Meteor.Collection('players');
 PlayersList = new Meteor.Collection('players');
```

to just:

```
PlayersList = new Meteor.Collection('players');
```

Answer (score 0):

you must to create the collection of **follows way**

```
PlayersList = new Meteor.Collection('players');
```

and you have to **pay attention** where you create this collection, because if you want have this collection in the two sides, client and server, you must create the collection in one archive outside of  client and server folder. This collection you can use in all your application.